# zero divisor graphs of a ring

Tags: graph-theory, ring-theory

If zero divisor graphs of two finite dimensional algebra are isomorphic does that imply that two algebra are isomorphic as a ring or a vector space?I would also like to know if graph theoretic isomorphism between two arbitary finite rings at all implies isomorphism between two rings?